# Saving data(octet-stream) from request as Excel file results in corrupted file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blob

I'm returning an Excel file (which works fine) as octet stream from C# API using `FileContentResult(byte[], MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "file.xlsx"`

and then I'd want to open download file prompt from js and everything works fine except that the file is corrupted

I've been trying various solutions from these posts and Excel file always result in being corrupted

[JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

[JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)

[Create binary blob in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949152/create-binary-blob-in-js)

and also `FileSaver.js`

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'POST',
data: formData,
processData: false,
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function (result) 
{
    saveFile(result);
}
});
```

I know that file is working fine because when I'm testing it via Swagger then it works fine

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

Returning base64 of that file and create `a` element on that page with `href` attribute that has value of

`data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,`

and then add your `base64` to that value, so

`'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,'+base64`

and then perform `.click()` on that link

[Conversion of Base64 Encoded into XSLX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921856/conversion-of-base64-encoded-into-xslx)

You can specify name of file by using `download=""` attribute

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is adding `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` to the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  },
  success: function (data) {
    const blob = new Blob([data]);
    saveAs(blob, "output.xlsx");
  }
});
```